# What persistent changes can I make to an Amazon Beanstalk configuration?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-beanstalk

([Cross posted to AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=78826))

We have a static family of static websites we're thinking of hosting on Amazon Beanstalk.
We currently depend on ssh access for our deployment process:

- We upload a zip file and unzip locally `unzip version.zip`
- We maintain symlinks to have shorter alias for some component (e.g. instead of http://oursite.com/verylongcustomername/somemoredetails we user http://oursite.com/K38da/Mc7za
- We're using quick rollback and patching on the server by editing specific files: `mv latest_ver latest_ver.bak;mv older_ver latest_ver` and `vim foo.js`

We're considering moving to Amazon Beanstalk, and so I installed and configured a sample website. I setup a symlink structure, uploading a version via scp, and edited Tomcat's configuration files. However, I'm not sure if any of these changes are maintained by the Beanstalk manager (in fact I saw some of them did not take when an instance was restarted).

Is there any way to have the Beanstalk manager remember local changes I do to the instance's filesystem, and carry that over to new instances it creates?

If the answer is no, then it seems I should forget about Beanstalk and use an EC2 image directly (I can then create an AMI that includes my custom modifications and relaunch if needed).

Answer (score 0):

To retain those kinds of changes you'll want to use your own AMI that has those changes made already so that when Beanstalk launches or re-launches the instances your data is present.

Alternatively you can use the .config files to automate the process as seen here:  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html